# Optimize returning top results from intersecting Sorted Set and Set in Redis

Tags: ruby, optimization, heroku, redis, scalability

I am trying to optimize my Redis code and I am currently having some difficulties scaling my solution. Redis is hosted on Redis Cloud, the app on Heroku and I am using Ruby for my language.

**My Redis setup:**

I have a series of sorted sets which each contains approx 1,000 scored members and a corresponding set (which could be a hash, string, list, set, sorted set or any other structure) for each user in the system.

For example in the news:sports key I have the following structure. Other keys examples are news:entertainment, news:business.

*news:sports -- Member Score*

```
StoryOID1 1000
StoryOID2 999
StoryOID3 998
StoryOID4 997
StoryOID5 996
...
```

I also have a user specific key (a set) for each of the master sorted sets (user1:news:sports) that contain a list of stories the user has already seen. ie

```
seen:user1:sports StoryOID2
```

**My challenge:**

On each user request, I need to return the top 3 members (with the highest scores, although I don't need to know the scores) from a specific sorted set that the user hasn't already seen. I prefer not to save the result in Redis as have no long term use and I will just have to delete the key.

Given the example above, User1 requests sports:news, I would return:

```
StoryOID1
StoryOID3
StoryOID4
```

As part of my code, I loop through 10 sorted sets (10 genres) returning the top 3 unseen stories from each for a total of 30 OIDS being returned for each request.

For each user request:

```
Do this 10 times:         
     ZRANGEBYSCORE top 24 members
     loop user genres key using SISMEMBER until I return 3 unseen members
end
```

Benchmarking at 60 dynos (heroku) on I can only get to 500 simultaneous connections (and at 1000 ms response time) with the Redis loop below being the bottleneck. I am aiming to scale a few multiples over my current setup. Anything and Everything can be change to scale this process.

My Current Process (in Ruby):

```
def newslist (userOID,genres)

    #pull top 24 stories for the given news:genres -- 24 could be replaced by 1,3,6,12 etc
    newsscores = @@redis.zrevrangebyscore("news:#{genres}", "+inf", "-inf", :limit => [0, 24],:with_scores => true)  

    newsstories = Array.new(3)
    i = 0 #news acceptance counter
    loopcnt = 0 #loop counter
    while i < 3 
      if newsscores.count == loopcnt - 1 #loop to the max number of news returned in news news
        break #breakout of loop
      end
      seen = @@redis.sismember("seen:#{userOID}:#{genres}", newsscores[loopcnt][0])
      if seen == false
        newsstories[i] = newsscores[loopcnt][0]
        i+=1
      end
      loopcnt += 1
    end
    if i==3
      return newsstories #return 3 news newss
    else
      return 0 #return 0 -- this should cause a repick
    end
    return 0 #return 0 -- this should cause a repick
end
```

I know I am paying a large costs the large number of Redis requets. My current thought process is to basically translate the above into a Lua script I can run on the server side but I can't help but feel there is a more elegant solution that will scale far better.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Any reason why you're calling sismember each time? You can call it just once before the loop IIUC. (BTW - thanks for using our service!)

Comment: The challenge is I don't know how many times to call it.

Comment: I use sismembers in the loop as I stop once I obtain the top 3 unseen members. I am trying to limit the overhead of puling sismembers of members 4 -24 (unless they are needed). The embedded nature of the loop and scaled to 1000's of simultaneous requests would seem to generate a lot of unneeded load on the servers.

Comment: right - I wasn't thinking straight :) Let me mull on this a little more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, yes: you should 100% be using Lua for this. Check the CPU on your Redis box. I'm willing to bet it's not burning up. Your bottleneck at this point is almost definitely network throughput because you're requiring a back-and-forth call each time you hit SISMEMBER (which is up to 24 times PER USER). That's a lot of unnecessary network activity. It's especially unnecessary when you consider that the logic you're doing on top of SISMEMBER could very easily be done server side, and there's really no reason to send anything back to your client until you finish the loop completely. That logic applies to the initial `ZRANGEBYSCORE top 24 members` as well. You can literally just translate the entire:

```
Do this 10 times:         
     ZRANGEBYSCORE top 24 members
     loop user genres key using SISMEMBER until I return 3 unseen members
end
```

into Lua and go from 250 network hits per user to just 1 per user. That will be a huge, huge win. On top of that, you'll be sending a lot less information to Redis and back the one time you do initiate a Redis call. Here's some Lua *pseudo-code* that should give you the idea of what you want to be doing:

```
local genres = {KEYS[1], KEYS[2], KEYS[3], KEYS[4], KEYS[5], KEYS[6], KEYS[7], KEYS[8], KEYS[9], KEYS[10]}
local user_seen_genre_sets = {KEYS[11], KEYS[12], KEYS[13], KEYS[14], KEYS[15], KEYS[16], KEYS[17], KEYS[18], KEYS[19], KEYS[20]}
local user_id = ARGV[1]

to_return = {{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}}
for i = 1, #genres do
  possible_stories = redis.call('ZREVRANGEBYSCORE', genres[i], 'inf', 0, 'LIMIT', 0, 24)
  --call SISMEMBER on each story above with the appropriate user_unseen_genre_sets key
  --add the first 3 results to to_return[i], then stop the loop.
end

return to_return
```

**Why use Lua instead of a pipeline?**

Itamar Haber brought up a good point that you might want to use broken up pipelines for this instead of a single Lua script because the Lua script might block your Redis server for too long. Here's a few reasons for why you want to use a Lua script instead of broken up pipelines:

1. I've never seen a single Lua script on Redis that doesn't do something like KEYS(*) take longer than 10s of milliseconds. None of the costs of the operations mentioned should be considered more than log(n) either, so you're pretty future proofed as well in case you're expecting large data growth. If your Redis server is being blocked for too long, that's more an indication that you need a bigger server because none of the operations you're running are very intense (log(n) at most, as mentioned).
2. One of the major benefits of the Lua script is you are sending your logic to be run server-side instead of sending a bunch of data back and forth to run your logic client-side (i.e. Get all the possible stories and send them to the client. Now send them each back to Redis one by one to run an ISMEMBER). All of that data being sent over the network will be a much bigger bottle neck than running more operations within Redis and Lua, both of which are very, very fast.

So, all in all, despite the valid question, I firmly stand by the Lua approach. If you care to run benchmarks and share them with us, that would be really awesome, because I'm guessing switching this over will improve things around two orders of magnitude.

Comment: Great answer @Eli - network is penalty is certainly key here, but I would be careful about Lua-izing the entire thing since in the more extreme cases (>>24) it could potentially block other clients... As a compromise I would first try to pipeline some of the stuff (at the sake of effectiveness [i.e. stopping after 3 matches]) and "batch" some of the operations. For example, do the ZREVRANGEBYSCORE and then pipeline all of the SISMEMBER.

Comment: @ItamarHaber I've responded above. Thanks for bringing up the point!

Comment: @Eli - Thanks for the insight. In most of my cases I find that 24 members of the ZREVRANGEBYSCORE by score is overkill (initially I did it to limit a few extra redis calls). In the lua script, am I better off pulling 6 (or 12) members of the ZREVRANGEBYSCORE and looping if required for 7-24? Redis documentation seems to suggest the big(O) is equivalent on a zrangebyscore or 6 or 24 members as long as the limit is constant. Are there other costs I should be aware of?

Comment: @tjrburgess yeah, the difference will be a constant, and neither call will be particularly expensive since you're not sending the data anywhere. You're very unlikely to experience a difference, and it sounds like premature optimization. You'll need to build in a "get more if needed" clause either way, in case even 24 items isn't enough. If you really want, you can benchmark for the ideal number, but until your site gets very, very large, you're really fine just guessing at it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use Lua scripting here, though depending on your data size, Lua versions of this calculation may be faster (depending on SISMEMBER vs. ZUNIONSTORE vs. SDIFFSTORE + ZINTERSTORE performance). Generally, you can calculate everything you want without multiple round-trips and without Lua scripting, provided the following 3 assumptions.

1. Your ZSETs all use positive non-zero scores (it is easier if all scores are >1, I will assume this)
2. Your SETs all contain the same members as your sorted sets
3. The maximum score in your ZSETs is fixed, or can at least be bounded (something like 1000000 is perfectly reasonable)

The important operation here is ZUNIONSTORE, which can take SETs as input, and whose members behave as though all scores are 1.

To get the top 3 stories from your news ZSETs, excluding those stories already read by a given user, you can make the following calls:

```
ZUNIONSTORE temp 2 news:sports seen:user1:sports WEIGHTS 1 -1000000
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE temp inf 0 LIMIT 0 3
DEL temp
```

You can wrap that with a MULTI/EXEC transaction so you don't have any extra data laying around after the query, pipeline it all, etc. This one has a limitation that as your number of stories read and the number of stories in each category increases, this one performs slower.

As an alternative, if you had a secondary SET that had the same members as (for example) your news:sports ZSET, you could instead perform:

```
SDIFFSTORE temp news:sports:set seen:user1:sports
ZINTERSTORE temp 2 temp news:sports WEIGHTS 0 1
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE temp inf -inf LIMIT 0 3
DEL temp
```

That would eliminate the score requirements, though would increase data size for each of your stories by an entry in a SET. This one also gets slower for every entry in the news SET, ZSET, and the user's seen SET, but the constants are different, so may be faster depending on your data sizes.

Comment: ZUNIONSTORE is an incredibly slow operation that grows at a pace of M*log(M) where M is the size of all unique elements in both sets. If you plan on having a lot of stories at any point in the future, this will quickly become your bottle neck. Nearly the same is true for the second approach. Both of the above answers will be a little faster to implement than doing this in Lua, but they will be slower now, and much, much slower in production. You don't gain anything by using them except for marginally faster development time. I can't think of any good reason to use them.

Comment: Benchmarking actual code shows that Lua can be ~3-13 times faster than either of the methods I describe, using story ZSET sizes of 1000 as the op offered. While in this context ZUNIONSTORE isn't the fastest option, calling it generally "an incredibly slow operation" is missing the point: it's exactly as fast as it needs to be to do its job (modulo optimizations that might make it faster).